# Mesh objects and SVG

Tags: svg, mesh, svg-animate, morphing

i have a question concerning mesh objects in SVG. I have an image that contains svg paths and points and image like this

```
<image width="189" height="773" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR..long string
```

This string represents a the mesh object. Now, my question is, is it possible to morph one mesh object into the other by only animating their paths, which i have?
Or how do you get this data into path form or something that is usable with SVG?

Comment: You say you have an image with SVG paths but the image is a png. Which is it because it can't be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illustrator makes the mesh into an image when exporting to svg, so i made another svg without the mesh, it doesnt have any more of that extra code embedding the mesh.